# Pass the particular value as a parameter in Load runner script

Tags: c, batch-file, performance-testing, loadrunner

I have automated a batch file through load runner script which writes the data in a notepad file.

Now I want to pass that written data in another load runner script as a parameter.

The data written from batch file looks like this:

```
USING API KEY : Android
Base URL = /user/authorization
HEADERS :
accessKey = 45k907its35dooeo182dm0guy8k0dv8o
signature = Tdo0ZBfZazTvYd8UwmHT+haq2vM=
timestamp = 1455397355435enter
```

But  when I want to read and pass the parameter in another script I just want to pass the `access key`.

How do I capture only access key from the batch file output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```
@Echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (data.txt) do If /i "%%a"=="accessKey " set "$Key=%%b"

Echo KEY ==^> [%$Key: =%]
```

Comment: Yes just use `%$Key: =%` example : `echo %$Key: =%`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Virtual Table server if you want to pass live during a test.  At the onset of a test all data files are loaded into RAM for the duration of the test, so any writes to a data file will only be available at the onset of the next test when the altered data file can be loaded.  The Virtual Table Server solves this by acting as a queue to pass information between virtual users during the execution of the test.

So you have a structural design issue in the test on how the information is being passed which needs to be addressed in order to meet your goal of information capture by 'A,' and then passed to 'B.'